# I have 2 date fields and I want records that fall into 1 or both

Tags: sql, date, where-clause

I have 2 date fields and I am trying to use OR in the where clause. As an example,

```
Select customer_records.customer_id, customer_records.join_date, rejected_customers.rejected_date, status_lookup.status_description 
From customer_records, rejected_customers, status_lookup
Where status_lookup.status_id(+) = customer_records.status_id and customer_records.customer_id = rejected_customers.customer_id
and (customer_records.join_date between to_date('01-10-2012','dd-mm-yyyy') and to_date('01-11-2012','dd-mm-yyyy') or rejected_customers.rejected_date between to_date('01-10-2012','dd-mm-yyyy') and to_date('01-11-2012','dd-mm-yyyy')
```

so, the basic outcome should be, I want customer_id's when the join date OR the rejected date falls into my date fields. I can't seem to get it to work, any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: When you say you can't get it to work, what do you mean? Do you get an error message, or the wrong data, or what?

Comment: Also, what RDMS are you using?

Comment: oracle 10, and I don't get an error message, but I get incorrect data. I only get customer_records.join_date and not a complete list of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select cr.customer_id, cr.join_date, rej.rejected_date
from customer_records cr left join rejected_customers rej on cr.customer_id=reg.customer_id
where (cr.join_date between to_date('01-10-2012','dd-mm-yyyy') and to_date('01-11-2012','dd-mm-yyyy')) or (rej.rejected_date between to_date('01-10-2012','dd-mm-yyyy') and to_date('01-11-2012','dd-mm-yyyy'))
```

Comment: Just seen the comments above - this information would greatly help. However, I'm guessing that you only have records for rejections in the cases where a rejection occurred, and therefore a regular join will only match those records having a rejection. A left join (this is MS-SQL syntax) will include all records and give a rejection date of NULL if there is no match in the rejection table. You should also alias your tables (eg `cr` instead of `customer_records`) as it's easier to follow.

Comment: Hey Chris K, I think I need to give you more information. When I did your suggestion, I received an error: outer join operator (+) not allowed in operand of OR or IN. I didn't know that the outer join would affect this situation because I thought it was just my logical error. I updated the code to reflect an outer join.

Answer (score 0):

When you say you can't seem to get it to work, I presume you run the query and you don't get the expected results and you don't get any errors.
Sometimes, some date fields are stored in the database with time fractions. so you need to use "trunc" function. See this example in Oracle database:

```
SQL> select to_char(sysdate,  'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss') date_no_trunc from dual;

DATE_NO_TRUNC
-------------------
28/03/2013 10:04:27

SQL> select to_char(trunc(sysdate),  'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss') date_with_trunc from dual;

DATE_WITH_TRUNC
-------------------
28/03/2013 12:00:00

SQL>
```

So you need to change your query to be like this:

```
Select c.customer_id,
       c.join_date,
       r.rejected_date
From   customer_records c,
       rejected_customers r
Where  c.customer_id = r.customer_id
and   ( trunc(c.join_date) between to_date('01-10-2012','dd-mm-yyyy') and to_date('01-11-2012','dd-mm-yyyy')
        or
        trunc(r.rejected_date) between to_date('01-10-2012','dd-mm-yyyy') and to_date('01-11-2012','dd-mm-yyyy')
      )
```

Also, it's always a good idea to give long table names aliases, this makes your query shorter and uses less memory.

Comment: ok i'll try this, thanks. (i would respond immediately, but i have to step out for a meeting).

Comment: the trunc didn't change anything.

Comment: post some sample rows from your tables please and say what you expect to get from the sample rows. This will enable us to understand your problem better.